# How to access all the options provided to a Jade template

Tags: javascript, pug

When you render a template, you can provide `options` that are available in the code of the template:

```
jade.renderFile('template.jade', { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" })
```

and the template:

```
div #{key1}
```

Is there a way to access the object that stores the options?

I would need to use that object like (Jade template):

```
- console.dir(optionsObject)
div #{optionsObject.key1}
```

I already checked `this`, but this points to the NodeJs global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you're looking for is `locals`:

```
div #{ locals.key1 }
```

Be aware that the object may also contains some keys that you didn't set explicitly (but are set by Jade internally).